# How to effectively alias a user on linux

Tags: linux, users

What's the best way to create a user alias in linux, such that 2 logins are, effectively, the same user?

So, I could do (or something pretty close):

```
sudo adduser primary_user
sudo useradd -d /home/primary_user -G primary_user -K UMASK=022 alias_user
sudo passwd alias_user
```

Which, at the start of this process these users will operate identically. But, if I run

`usermod -aG docker $USER`

I don't see how the aliased user will now, suddenly, be part of the docker group. Am I missing something? I literally want 2 logins, 1 user account:

`jbrown -> jbrown`

`jbro -> jbrown`

Can this effectively be done? This may have a distro specific answer

Comment: I'm curious to understand what problem you're trying to solve here that would need an aliased user account

Comment: I'll make this simple: I get client laptops with variations of my username and I want to be able to ssh into some common machines without having to always qualify the user AND not have to manage user accounts. It's not a production grade issue, but it's an annoyance

Comment: Rather than creating a new aliased account can't you simply rename the incorrect original?

Comment: No, because I have both correct and incorrect usernames active at the same time. 
so my local name is `jbrown` and on the remote it's `jbrown`, this is on client machine 1. On client machine 2, my name is `jbro` but I still need to access the same remote as above. So I would need to do: `ssh jbrown@...` instead of just `ssh @...`. Like I said, an annoyance. And, it happens a lot

Comment: Ugh! Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users can share their UID, giving them the same user permissions.

Some quick testing reveals that no matter which alias you are logged in as, the system will recognize you as the first user which matches the UID from the `passwd` database (normally `/etc/passwd` but can be elsewhere in advanced setups).

I have not seen that groups behave the same way, each alias needs to be added to each group explicitly.  It would seem that while users are mapped from UID, the groups look to be mapped from the name (check the contents of `/etc/group` to get a sense of what I mean).

Quick example based on what you started with:

```
#!/bin/sh

USER1=primary
USER2=alias

sudo adduser $USER1
sudo useradd -d /home/$USER1 -G $USER1 -K UMASK=022 --non-unique --uid $(id -u $USER1) --no-create-home --no-user-group $USER2
sudo passwd $USER2

# --non-unique: Allow the creation of a user account with duplicate UID
# --uid: The numerical value of the user's ID
# --no-create-home: Do not create the user's home directory.
# --no-user-group: Do not create a group with the same name as the user.
```

At this point, you should have two users with the same UID sharing the same home directory both belonging to the `$USER1` group.

To add them each to the `docker` group, you would have to add them separately:

```
usermod -aG docker $USER1
usermod -aG docker $USER2
```

Though it is probably easier to just add the `docker` group when you create the alias:

```
sudo useradd -d /home/$USER1 -G ${USER1},docker -K UMASK=022 --non-unique --uid $(id -u $USER1) --no-create-home --no-user-group $USER2
```

As an alternative, you could change the Docker configuration to use the `$USER1` group for authorization which is already shared between those users instead of the `docker` group.

Comment: "Who the user is" is soley determined by the `[UID:GID]` of the user, determined by their entry in `/etc/{passwd,shadow}`. Read `man 5 passwd`. I have not, in my 55+ years computing experience, seen a valid use of "multiple users with same UID". I have seen project disaster/lsst-minute redesign,  through. Read `man sudo sudoers`, consider adding the users to a project specific group,  and allowing group access to the shared files?

Comment: Following up: There were a few things out of place in /etc/passwd (like the shell, and the group id). I manually changed them and now this works as expected. Thanks